# How to customize user during RemoteUserBackend authentication

Tags: python, django

I copied the RemoteUserBackend class from Django and modified it to do check if the remote_user that is connecting is in a specific LDAP group before continuing with the authentication. If the user has never logged on before the user is populated in Django's database. I'm trying to figure out how to set the first_name, last_name, and email fields as well as make the user stuff and a superadmin. This is the code that I have. It's part of the RemoteUserBackend class. I'm doing something wrong. The LDAP lookup is fine but the user isn't changed.

```
def configure_user(self, user):
    """
    Configures a user after creation and returns the updated user.

    By default, returns the user unmodified.
    """
    con = ldap.initialize(settings.AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI)
    bind_dn = settings.AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN
    bind_pw = settings.AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD
    con.simple_bind_s(bind_dn, bind_pw)

    base_dn = settings.AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN
    attrs = ['givenName', 'sn', 'mail']
    filter = '(SAMAccountName={0})'.format(user.username)
    ldap_user = con.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs)

    givenName = ldap_user[0][1]['givenName'][0].decode('utf-8')
    sn = ldap_user[0][1]['sn'][0].decode('utf-8')
    mail = ldap_user[0][1]['mail'][0].decode('utf-8')

    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superadmin = True
    user.first_name = givenName
    user.last_name = sn
    user.email = mail
    user.save()
    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue....slightly embarrassing...

It should have been user.is_superuser = True, not user.is_superadmin = True